# Alternative for 'addRule(int)' in ActionBar.LayoutParams like addRule in RelativeLayout.LayoutParams?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-relativelayout, layoutparams

My code below works when placed in a class extending [Activity class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) but **addRule** gives compile error saying it is undefined when I am extending [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html).

```
Error:
The method addRule(int) is undefined for the type ActionBar.LayoutParams
```

**Question**: What is the alternative to [addRule(int) in RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule%28int%29) in [ActionBar.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.LayoutParams.html)??

```
private void initializeSlidingLayer() {
    LayoutParams myrlp = (LayoutParams) mySlidingLayer.getLayoutParams();

    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);



    //for bottom
    mySlidingLayer.setStickTo(SlidingLayer.STICK_TO_BOTTOM);


    myrlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM); //THIS LINE THROWS ERROR WITH ACTIONBARACTIVITY
    myrlp.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT; 
    myrlp.height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.layer_width);

  //Adding Shadow
    mySlidingLayer.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    mySlidingLayer.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.sidebar_shadow);

        //mSlidingLayer.setOffsetWidth(0);
    mySlidingLayer.setOffsetWidth(getResources().getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.offset_width));    
}
```

Probably not relevant to the question, but I am trying to [this SlidingLayer Library](https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure action bar uses a relative layout?  If not, then you can't treat it as a relative layout layout params and can ONLY use the base layoutParams functions

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own questions - but I just thought of something to try (that worked) after I hit Submit.

Instead of importing:

```
 import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
```

I needed to import:

```
 import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;
```

I am still able to import extend ActionBarActivity.